# Find out which exactly items have been deleted?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose we run a query with dynamic conditions, which was initiated from user input. And we want to delete some items.

Such as (just a random example):

```
DELETE FROM pictures
WHERE article = 10
    AND id >= 12
    AND id <= 25
    AND user_privelege = 8
```

Is there any way to retrieve which exactly rows have been deleted?

Comment: Well, not without a transaction including a separate SELECT step with the same conditions (ie BEGIN/SELECT/DELETE/COMMIT) or a pre-existing trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You will need to select from the table using the exact same `WHERE` clause beforehand.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if we have some constraints that would restrict us from deleting them, or perhaps some other error (if the query is a little bit more complex).